# C# Windows Form search txt file for passed data and pass to textboxes

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, multidimensional-array

I'm relatively new to C# and have spent an inordinate amount of time trying to figure this out myself with no luck. Hoping you guys can help.

I have 2 windows forms. In the first form, the user enters a citation number. I want to take that citation number, search for it in an external text file, and then return all of the data in the row for that citation into separate textboxes.

The text file looks something like this:

```
S8729936 , 6JXV123 , 10/1/2015 , 10/31/2015 , PAID , 49.5
A7472601 , 2NXP234 , 10/12/2015 , 11/11/2015 , UNPAID , 99
W2041810 , 5JPB345 , 10/19/2015 , 11/18/2015 , UNPAID , 99
```

And the second form has 6 textboxes. I have it so that the citation number, let's say S8729936 is passed into the first textbox, but I cannot seem to figure out how to then search the text file for S8729936 and give me the rest of the data in the row inside the textboxes.

Here are some examples of things I've tried. I've been copying and pasting and then messing with code all day, so if the details don't seem to match, that's probably the reason.

```
public Form2(string citation)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtCitation2.Text = citation;

        const string FILENAME = @"\Path\ProjectData.txt";
        FileStream fsInFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader srReader = new StreamReader(fsInFile);

        const char CH_DELIM = ',';
        string strRecordIn;
        string[] strFields;

        if (strFields != null)
        {
            strRecordIn = srReader.ReadLine();
            strFields = strRecordIn.Split(CH_DELIM);
            txtLicense2.Text = strFields[1];
        }
strRecordIn = srReader.ReadLine();

        srReader.Close();
        fsInFile.Close();
    }
```

No luck there, how about something along the lines of this:

```
string whole_file = File.ReadAllText(@"Path\ProjectData.txt");
        whole_file = whole_file.Replace('\n', '\r');
        string[] lines = whole_file.Split(new char[] { '\r' });

        int num_rows = lines.Length;
        int num_cols = lines[0].Split(',').Length;

        string[,] values = new string[num_rows, num_cols];

        for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)
        {
            string[] line_r = lines[r].Split(',');
            for (int c = 0; c < num_cols; c++)
            {
                values[r, c] = line_r[c];
            }
        }

        txtLicense2.Text = lines[1];
```

Nope. Maybe something along the lines of this:

```
const string FILENAME = @"C:\Users\rfranklin\Documents\ProjectData.txt";
        FileStream fsinfile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader srReader = new StreamReader(fsinfile);

        const string CH_DELIM = " ,";
        string strRecordIn;
        string[] strFields = new string[10];
        string citnum = citation;
        bool found = false;

        strRecordIn = srReader.ReadLine();

        foreach(string x in strFields)
        {
            if (x == citation)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found)
        {
            txtLicense2.Text = strFields[1];
        }
```

Still no luck. And on and on. It seems as though I'm mostly missing how to tell the program what to search for and I am not sure what else to do. Like I said, I've been Googling various ways to do it all day, but I can't seem to make anything work right.

I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2013, if that helps.

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to loop the file contents. You are just reading first line and processing it. You need to put ReadLine() inside the loop.

Comment: How many lines are there in your file ? Do you have control over the format of this file, or is it provided to you as a CSV ? Any possibility to convert it to a database table (Access, MS SQL, etc...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from @interceptwind did it for me. Inside the //output section of the code he provided, I basically just created a second array from the matched line, with the elements separated by the comma. The code looks like this:

```
        //output
        foreach (string s in matchedList)
        {
            string citationLine = s;
            string[] lineData = citationLine.Split(',');
            txtLicense2.Text = lineData[1];
            txtIssued2.Text = lineData[2];
            txtDue2.Text = lineData[3];
            txtStatus2.Text = lineData[4];
            txtAmount2.Text = lineData[5];
        }
```

This allowed me to put the data in the textboxes I needed. Thank you all for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If the number of lines in the CSV file is not too large (I wouldn't know what "too large" is), then you could leverage a few .NET constructs, such as Data Binding and Linq to achieve this.

For starters, I would create a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
namespace Citations
{
    public class Citation : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public static Citation ParseLine(string line)
        {
            Citation cit = new Citation();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument", nameof(line));

            string[] vals = line.Split(',');

            if (vals.Length != 6)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(line), "Invalid format");

            cit.CitationNumber = vals[0].Trim();
            cit.PlateNumber = vals[1].Trim();
            cit.DateCreated = DateTime.Parse(vals[2].Trim());
            cit.DateExpired = DateTime.Parse(vals[3].Trim());
            cit.Status = vals[4].Trim();
            cit.Amount = Decimal.Parse(vals[5].Trim());

            return cit;

        }

        void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        string citationNumber;
        public string CitationNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return citationNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                if (citationNumber != value)
                {
                    citationNumber = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CitationNumber));
                }
            }
        }

        string plateNumber;
        public string PlateNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return plateNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                if (plateNumber != value)
                {
                    plateNumber = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PlateNumber));
                }
            }
        }

        DateTime dateCreated;
        public DateTime DateCreated
        {
            get
            {
                return dateCreated;
            }
            set
            {
                if (dateCreated != value)
                {
                    dateCreated = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DateCreated));
                }
            }
        }
        DateTime dateExpired;
        public DateTime DateExpired
        {
            get
            {
                return dateExpired;
            }
            set
            {
                if (dateExpired != value)
                {
                    dateExpired = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DateExpired));
                }
            }
        }

        string status;
        public string Status
        {
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
            set
            {
                if (status != value)
                {
                    status = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
                }
            }
        }

        Decimal amount;
        public Decimal Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return amount;
            }
            set
            {
                if (amount != value)
                {
                    amount = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Amount));
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

This class is responsible for splitting a line from the CSV file, and converting it to an object of type `Citation`, which will be used to data bind the textboxes in Form2 later on.

Then in the first Form, I would simply read the file, and using some Linq operators, convert the file to a Dictionary of Citation objects, the key of the Dictionary being the Citation number:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("Citations.csv");

    Dictionary<string, Citation> dict = allLines.Select(l => Citation.ParseLine(l)).ToDictionary(c => c.CitationNumber, k => k);

    Citation cit = dict["W2041810"];

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.SetCitation(cit);
    frm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

In the code above, we're using the `ToDictionary` Linq operator to create a Disctionary from your Citation objects, and the Dictionat key is the Citation number.

Here I'm hardcoding one of the citations for lookup and passing to Form2, which would have a `SetCitation` method like this:

```
public void SetCitation(Citation citation)
{
    this.citationBindingSource.DataSource = citation;
}
```

The code to Form2 is a bit difficult to show because I have used the Form designer to setup the data binding for each TextBox, and if I wanted to show that, I'd basically have to show the whole Form2.Designer.cs file.

Instead, I propose to guide you through the process of creating a Project DataSource, then drag & drop the TextBoxes onto Form2 from the Data Sources dialog in Visual Studio.

So, after adding the Citation class to your solution, make sure to compile at leat once so that the "Add data source" wizard will pick that class up as a possible data source.

Then, make sure the Data Sources dialog is displayed by going to View > Other Windows > Data Sources (assuming Visual Studio 2015 here).

From the Data Sources dialog, click the "Add New Data Source button" tolaunch the Data SOurce Configuration Wizard. From the list of possible data sources, you will choose "Object":

[image: Data Source]

Then click the Next button. From the next Wizard step, you will select the `Citation` class:

[image: Select Citation class]

and then click the Finish button.

In the Data Sources dialog, you should now have something like this:

[image: Data Sources]

From this Data Sources dialog, you can now drag & drop the individual fields onto Form2, which should give you something like this:

[image: Form2 layout]

You will also notice in the Component tray of Form2, a BindingSource object has been added:

[image: Citation Binding Source]

Under the hood, Visual Studio will have set all the Data Binding for your Citation object properties to be displayed in the corresponding TextBox.

This is the "glue" that makes it possible to call Form2.SetCitation() with a Citation object, and have all the fields displayed where they should.

I know this is quite a mouthful to chew on, but believe me, once you understand the principles behind this, you will not want to go back to the kind of spagethi code that you started implementing (no offense, we've all been there).

If you would like me to clarify any specific section of my answer, just let me know, and I'll edit accordingly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A simple winForm version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> matchedList = new List<string>();

        public Form1(string citation)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string filePath = @"C:\Users\rfranklin\Documents\ProjectData.txt";
            string[] linesArr = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            //find matches
            foreach(string s in linesArr)
            {
                if(s.Contains(citation))
                {
                    matchedList.Add(s); //matched
                }
            }

            //output
            foreach(string s in matchedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s); //write to console
                //or output to wherever you wish, eg.
                //richTextBox.Text += s + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that Form1 needs to be called from somewhere else and take in `citation` argument. To test it standalone, change it to

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string citation = "S8729936";
```